# Websocket library for python

Tags: python, google-chrome, websocket

Hi I need a websocket server in python which supports the protocol used in chrome 16(protocol version 13). Tornado and twisted are not working. Websockify works but i can't find any documentation for it. I need minimal setup means lesser imports. Please help me out here thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps [gevent-websocket](http://www.gelens.org/code/gevent-websocket/).

Answer (score 5):

- Maybe you could take a look to [pywebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/), it claims to support protocol version 13 and is designed for :

  > The pywebsocket project aims to provide a WebSocket standalone server
  >   and a WebSocket extension for Apache HTTP Server, mod_pywebsocket.
- [Autobahn](https://github.com/oberstet/Autobahn) is another implementation of websockets :

  > Autobahn WebSockets for Python provides an implementation of the
  >   WebSockets protocol which can be used to build WebSockets clients and
  >   servers
- [ws4py : Websocket for python](https://github.com/Lawouach/WebSocket-for-Python) :

  > Python library providing support for the WebSocket protocol defined in
  >   RFC 6455

Comment: i don't want to use standalone server and a WebSocket extension for Apache HTTP Server, mod_pywebsocket.

Comment: @user867609 : well, I added some other libraries to handle websockets. But if you don't want neither a standalone server nor apache mod, what do you need ?

Comment: sry I want a standalone server and ws4py dosen 't work on chrome 16(HyBi 13)

Comment: @user867609 : if you want a standalone server, why pywebsocket is not correct ? (you can launch it [without Apache](http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/source/browse/trunk/src/mod_pywebsocket/standalone.py))

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples of implementing a websocket server in Python. Be sure to read and apply the comments on the code of the following examples, because there may be some bugs:

- http://popdevelop.com/2010/03/a-minimal-python-websocket-server/ : It has been tested on Chrome, according to the author of the code.
- http://mumrah.net/websockets-in-python : At the end of this blog page, the author has included the URL to a Python implementation of a websocket server.
- http://dev.enekoalonso.com/2010/05/22/more-websockets-now-with-python/: only works on Chrome, according to the author.

Comment: This one is not working I already tried. It works in only few old browsers

Answer (score 0):

This page contains an implementation of a Python websocket server that can be used through imports:

https://github.com/AdrianGaudebert/python-websocket-server

You should know that the license for using this is MIT. It may only work with Python 3.0.

Comment: does it supports WS protocol version 13(hybi 13) used in chrome 16

Answer (score 0):

[WebSocket Echo example](https://gist.github.com/1380305) works on Chrome/16.0.912.63.

It uses [`txWS`](https://github.com/MostAwesomeDude/txWS) a [*simple library for adding WebSockets server support to your favorite Twisted applications*](https://github.com/MostAwesomeDude/txWS/blob/master/README.rst).

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested in using websockify, there is a simple example of using it to build an echo server included](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/blob/master/tests/echo.py).

You can run it like this (from a websockify checkout):

```
./tests/echo.py 8080
```

The browse to localhost:8080/tests/echo.html. Enter localhost, 8080 for the WebSocket host and port and hit connect. You should see the client sending messages and the server echoing them back (with a "You said: " prefix).